# Do Acceptance Testing of GUI actually show it when testing?

Tags: c#, java, acceptance-testing

When doing Acceptance Testings to the GUI, do tests to the GUI actually show the GUI (in a fraction of a second, I suppose) or are they just mock implementations? I'm talking about frameworks as WindowLicker, White, NUnitForms, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean automated testing. My interpretation of acceptance testing for a GUI involves people actually using the GUI to see if it does what it's supposed to do, in which case you obviously need to show the GUI.

In the test cases I've written for GUI components you usually create a genuine UI without mockups, but don't make it visible. Usually that is sufficient, and mockups of the higher level GUI components can be hard. However a lot of GUI components need to be part of a component tree to function  This means that you generally need to run on a machine which has a display, even if you don't use it. There are some functions where GUI components behave differently when they are visible, but I've been able to work round that, with a single exception involving JOGL.

Answer (score 1):

Last time i used it, NunitForms would show the actual Form being tested on screen. You could make it render the actual form off screen if you prefer.  I'm not sure about the others you mentioned, i have never used them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the others you mentioned but WindowLicker definitely shows the gui. I don't know if it's possible to run it without doing this, I never tried. It also takes longer than 'a fraction of a second'. You can watch it move the mouse pointer around, click on items, 'typing' text, etc.